# W/L Ratio of a MOSFET

Tags: transistors, mosfet

In the schematic builder that calculates voltages/currents/transient analysis that we have been provided for the electrical engineering course, MOSFETs have the parameter "W/L Ratio".

I figured that it was probably Width:Length, but how does that affect the constant K, and the voltage threshold? I realise that there is not enough information for absolute values, but really I'm looking for a formula that relates the variables.

So my question is, what is the relationship between W/L, K, and the threshold voltage of the MOSFET?

Comment: You're going to need to know a lot more about a transistor than its geometry to characterise it.  Also, we don't know which of the many constants that can describe a transistor is the one you call "K".  You should be able see for yourself this question is too vague with too much missing information.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with his question. His reference to K may be a little vague that is all.

Comment: I updated the question to make my intentions clearer

Comment: Ah, you're talking about designing the transistor itself, not building circuits out of them. The question still needs to be clearer though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The K constant you refer to (more specifically \$K_n\$) is called the conduction parameter of the n-channel device.

\$K_n\$ is given by:

$$K_n = \frac{k_n'}{2}\cdot\frac{W}{L}$$

Where

$$k_n' = \mu_nC_{ox}$$

\$\mu_n\$ is the mobility of the electrons in the inversion layer and \$C_{ox}\$ is the oxide capacitance per unit area. According to Neamen the \$k_n'\$ parameter is called the "process conduction parameter" and is considered to be a constant for a fabrication technology. Therefore the ratio \$\frac{W}{L}\$ is the transistor design variable.

Neamen goes on to say that the design variable is used to design MOSFETS to produce specific current-voltage characteristics in MOSFET circuits.

EDIT:

Yes w refers to width and L to length. It relates to the geometry of the semiconductor.

Comment: What about VT, the threshold voltage?

Comment: As I understand \$V_T\$ has little relation to the conductance parameter and is more reliant on the doping of the substrate however there should be some correlation between the two. In my course \$V_T\$ was always given as a separate variable.

Here is some more information: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threshold_voltage

Answer (score 3):

Just a few additions to Konsalik's answer:

\$V_T\$ (threshold voltage) is not affected by the W/L ratio of the transistor, as it depends on other parameters, such as the gate insulator thickness and dielectric constant; it also depends on Source-Bulk voltage, in what is called Body effect:

$$ V_{TB} = V_{T_0} + \gamma (\sqrt{V_{SB} + 2 \phi_{B} - \sqrt{2\phi_{B}}}) $$

Just as  note: usually in integrated circuits, L is limited by the technology (as small as possible) and the conductivity is increased with bigger W; in this way, though, also the gate capacitance is increased, so often it doesn't bring any advantage.

Comment: This is college stuff, too long ago for me. I never needed this in my professional career.

Comment: @stevenvh true, as it's also true that K is useless, since no datasheet gives that parameter :) and I'm not sure about W and L. But it makes sense in IC design

Comment: k' isn't given in IC design either - you usually end up deriving it from the level 3 SPICE models. Also, VT does/can change with different W/L ratios, but this is often ignored for simplicity.

Comment: @stevenvh, W and L are quite important when considering a given transistor for logic design (although practical usage has these parameters transparent since you are simply given the derivates of them. i.e. gate capacitance and resistance). To elabroate, the length (L) parameter specifices how *long* the channel is, while the width (W) specifies how *wide* the channel is. The gate input capacitance is directly proportional to L and the channel resistance (on-state resistance) is inversely proportional to W (i.e. wider *lanes* lower resistance, so to speak). When cascading gates, these

Comment: .. paramters contribute (actually *cause*, along with wire capacitance and resitance) the propagation delay seen. As a side note, the reports you may read that refer to transistor 20nm technology are referring to this L (channel length). So obviously with lower input capacitance (smaller L), the realized circuits can run faster.

Answer (score 0):

I performed an experiment to explore the relationship between threshold voltage and W and L separately but not the ratio of them. And the result is as shown below [image]
[image]
I suppose maybe threshold voltage is related to W or L separately but it is a constant when W and L increase as a constant ratio.
Hope this may be useful.